# MySQL remove Whitespace from fields (NOT using TRIM)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to remove white-space from a table fields, anyone will suggest to use TRIM however trim doesn't replace the white-space. So i used following but still no success

```
$sql=" UPDATE `search_si` SET title= TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(title,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r','')) WHERE 1  ";
```

strings like just complete blank space dont get removed from this, its is highlighted in the TRIM it wont remove all the white spaces, however i need another way to do this ? i.e remove all unvisible chars out.

example demo

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f3da/1

thanks

Comment: `TRIM` only replaces spaces at the ends, not in the middle. If you want to remove spaces in the middle, use `REPLACE(..., ' ', '')`

Comment: You need to be more specific. Seems you don't even know what you are trying to remove.

Comment: in php white space always trim, so why did you want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace spaces everywhere in the string, use `REPLACE`, not `TRIM`, since the latter only removes whitespace at the beginning and end of the string.

```
$sql=" UPDATE `search_si` SET title= REPLACE(REPLACE(Replace(Replace(Replace(title,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''), ' ', ''), CHAR(49824), '') WHERE 1  ";
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37a59e/3)

Comment: You don't have to include "WHERE 1".

Comment: this dint work, as i have highlighted in the the question, i already used this exact same function, this only removes certain characters

Comment: It works for me. You didn't use this exact same function, you used `TRIM` instead of `REPLACE`.

Comment: See the demo, it works.

Comment: this dotn replace the space i have as

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Maybe your table actually contains HTML `<br>` or `&nbsp;` markup?

Comment: There is a whole litney list of white space characters outside of spacebar, tab and newlines.  https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html   select hex(column_name) to get a hex dump of the actual character encodings.

Comment: see your example doent work for my data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f3da/1

Comment: Those aren't ASCII spaces, they're a multi-byte Unicode character. You'll need to add another `REPLACE()` call to replace them.

Comment: i didnt mention that i want to remove ASCII spaces, can you edit your solution so that i can have a try and see it works.

Comment: What is the character code for those whitespace characters? You can use the `CHAR()` function to create a string containing that character, and then use it in a `REPLACE()` call.

Comment: how do i know that, its just an unvisible charactor to me ..

Comment: just tried to check it in a hex editor and I'm getting the following sequence of characters: c2a0 20c2 a020 c2a0 and so on... 20 is the ascii space, A0 is the &nbsp; (non-breaking space) don't know about the other one